# Assignment expression in for/yield cause of Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

My codes looks like this:

```
  type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]
  def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = for {
    (theChar, theInt) <- x
    yMap = y.toMap
    finalInt = theInt - yMap.getOrElse(theChar,0)
    if finalInt != 0
  } yield (theChar, finalInt)
```

I was wondering whether `yMap= y.toMap` is evaluated only once or many times.. If it was evaluated many times, what would be the correct syntax to make it to be evaluated only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

Just bring the `ymap = y.toMap` part out of the `for` comprehension.

```
def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = {
    val yMap = y.toMap
    for {
      (theChar, theInt) <- x
      finalInt = theInt - yMap.getOrElse(theChar, 0)
      if finalInt != 0
    } yield (theChar, finalInt)
  }
```

### Detailed Answer

Scala [For Comprehensions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html) is just a syntactic sugar.

For instance your code will be translated to the following code by compiler (not exactly the following code but the concept is the same):

```
def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = x map {
    case (theChar, theInt) =>
      def yMap = y.toMap
      def finalInt = theInt - yMap.getOrElse(theChar, 0)
      (theChar, finalInt)
  } filter {
    case (_, theInt) =>
      theInt != 0
  }
```

So any expression inside the `map` part will be executed for every item of the collection (`x` in this case). By moving the `y = y.toMap` part out of the `for` block the code will be translated into :

```
  def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = {
    def yMap = y.toMap
    x map {
      case (theChar, theInt) =>
        def finalInt = theInt - yMap.getOrElse(theChar, 0)
        (theChar, finalInt)
    } filter {
      case (_, theInt) =>
        theInt != 0
    }
  }
```

which is most probably what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

It's evaluated once for every element of `x`; *everything* below the `(theChar, theInt) <- x` is.

If you want to evaluate something only once, keep it out of anything that loops over each element.  For example,

```
def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = {
  val yMap = y.toMap
  for {
    (theChar, theInt) <- x
    finalInt = theInt - yMap.getOrElse(theChar,0)
    if finalInt != 0
  } yield (theChar, finalInt)
}
```

would do the trick.